# Accessing model attributes in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models

I'm trying to show users the product variations that they have selected. While the code is working and saving the variation in the database, I am not being able to show them on my html page. Only `:` is being rendered. If I try `{{ order_item.variation.all }}` and it gives an empty queryset like : `<QuerySet []>`. And if I try `{{ order_item.variation }}`, it says : `products.Variation.None`. What is the problem? Is the way I'm calling it wrong? This is what I've tried:

My models.py:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variation_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_TYPES, default='Size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item  = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
```

My order_summary.html:

```
{% for order_item in object.items.all %}
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="border-0">
        <div class="p-2">
          <img src="{{ order_item.item.image_url }}" alt="" width="70" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
            <div class="ml-3 d-inline-block align-middle">
              <h5 class="mb-0"> <a href="{{ order_item.item.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-dark d-inline-block align-middle">{{ order_item.item.title }}</a>
              {% if order_item.variation %}
               <ul>
                 <h6>{{ order_item.variation.variation_type }} : {{ order_item.variation.title }}</h6>
               </ul>
             {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
       </th>
```

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user= request.user,
        ordered=False,
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.success(request, "Product quantity has been updated.")
        else:

            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
            return redirect("order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.success(request, "Product added to cart.")
        return redirect("order-summary")
    return redirect("order-summary")




class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'orders/order_summary.html', context)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")
```

Comment: You should do some refactoring in your models to make your code more readable and most probably fix you issue. ForeignKey and ManyToManyField should be declared with the parameter related_name, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name. In your View try to print(order.variation) and confirm its empty. The Order model shouldn't need Variation foreign key since OrderItem has it already

Comment: The users can select variation while adding a product to the cart. I've updated my question with the add_to_cart view. Is it happening because of it?

Comment: Yeah they can change the variation on the OrderItem... Doesn't make sense this has a DB model.

Comment: What should i do ?

Comment: Rethink your DB mode and implementation. And read the documentation regarding the related_name, super important for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: TBH i am lost....

Comment: Ok my friend, later I'll post a more concrete solution, to be more helpful

Comment: Thank you brother, counting on you :)... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor of `models.py`:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_variations', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variation_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_TYPES, default='Size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, related_name='order_item_variations', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

You can access your user's orders with the bellow example

```
first_user = User.objects.all().first()
orders = first_user.orders.all()
```

You can access your order's items with the bellow example

```
first_order = Order.objects.all().first()
order_items = first_order.order_items.all()
```

You need to refactor the html and views.py but it should be pretty straight forward

Comment: But brother won't it be a better idea to add 
`variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, related_name='order_item_variations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` on the Order model ? Because that's where I store all the order_items and everything

Comment: And if you don't mind, can you please show how do I add the variation part in my add_to_cart view and access it in my html please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No, because the variation is relative to the item not the order. For the first question

Comment: Regarding the second question you need to add a second slug to your urls and to the add_to_cart method and query the database and then add it to the order_item you're creating

Comment: But not every product will have variations

Comment: Updated OrderItem with your new information. This should be basic stuff you should know man. There some awesome tutorials on youtube I'm sure. You should also look up for database modelling and practice. That's very important